# Is supplying alike default special member functions a bad practice?

Tags: c++

We just have a discussion over here about explicitly declaring the [special member functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions). Is it bad practice doing so? What I mean: The compiler generated versions perform memberwise operations. If I'd implement  methods doing exactly the same (consider the [rule of three/five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)), besides that it is more work, is this a bad practice?

Of course, one could say it is redundant and bloats the code base. Others claim having explicit declarations simplifies debugging (e.g. as I can have breakpoints whenever the object is copied).

So is writing a class like `Explicit` (below, example based on [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions)) bad practice or just personal taste?

```
class Explicit {
    string msg;
public:
    Explicit() : msg("") {}
    Explicit(const Explicit& other) : msg(other.msg) {}
    Explicit& operator=(const Explicit& other) {
        if (this != &other) { msg = other.msg; }
        return *this;
    }
    ~Explicit()  {}
};
```

Comment: Bad practice: extra scope for error, and you lose the compiler generated move copy constructor and move assignment operator.

Comment: And without using `= default`, you lose not having a user-provided one, which can change the category of your class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real redundancy is in the fact that you will be mentioning your data members in the implementations of those special member functions.

Like all redundancy, this runs the risk that you'll one day change one, but not the other, e.g. add a data member and forget to update the special member functions.

There is nothing wrong with using the C++11 `= default` construct, since that avoids that particular redundancy.